# Prove that $\{I, T, ..., T^k\}$ is linearly dependent (LD) if and only if $\forall v \colon \{v, T(v), ..., T^k(v)\}$ is LD.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I want to solve this question, but my attempts failed :(

Assume that $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation on vector space $V$.

Prove that $I, T, T^2, ..., T^k$ are LD $\iff$ $\forall v \in V$:
$v, T(v), T^2(v), ..., T^k(v)$ are LD.

**My Attemps:**

1. Proof of $I, T, ..., T^k$ are LD $\Rightarrow$ $\forall v \in V$:
   $v, T(v), T^2(v), ..., T^k(v)$ are LD) is easy.

Assume that $I, T, ..., T^k$ are LD so exists $a_0, ..., a_k$ (where at least one of them isn't 0) and
$a_0 I + ... + a_k T^k = 0 \Rightarrow a_0 I(v) + ... + a_k T^k(v) = 0 \Rightarrow a_0 v + ... + a_k T^k(v) = 0 \Rightarrow $ $v, T(v), ..., T^k(v)$ are LD.

2. There are some facts that can be proved easily such as:

   - if $\forall v \in V$:
     $v, T(v), ..., T^k(v)$ are LD for all $v$ exists $a_{v, 0}, ..., a_{v, k-1} \in F$ that $T^k(v) = a_{v, 0} v + ... + a_{v, k-1} T^{k-1}(v)$

but I can't solve this problem with them :(

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The reciprocal can be proved by contradiction. Actually it is more easily stated as

> $\{I,T,T^2,\ldots,T^k\}$ is linearly independent (LI) $\implies$ $\exists v\in V\colon\{v,Tv,T^2v,\ldots,T^kv\}$  is LI.

Put this way the proof might be more straightforward.

Comment: Yes... I had just realized that. Fixed it, thx.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is this a proof of "$\forall v \colon \{v, T(v), ..., T^k(v)\}$ is LD $\Rightarrow$ $I, T, T^2, ..., T^k$ are LD" ? my real headache is it.

Comment: my question equivalent with "$\{I,T,T^2,\ldots,T^k\}$ is LI $\implies$ $\exists v\in V\colon\{v,Tv,T^2v,\ldots,T^kv\}$ is LI" (exists, not all)

Comment: Yes. That's the equivalence... sorry, clearly I'm not in my best day.

Comment: But I can't understand how can you solve the question with this equivalent! :(